# «Soquete» como tradução de «socket» é correto?

Tags: estrangeirismos, português-brasileiro

Nesta pergunta do Stackoverflow em Português, [Soquete bloqueante x Soquete não bloqueante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130716/soquete-bloqueante-x-soquete-n%C3%A3o-bloqueante) aparece ***soquete*** como tradução do inglês [socket (network socket, Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).

Eu já procurei em vários dicionários Portugueses e Brasileiros e não vi essa definição em nenhum deles.

> **so·que·te** |sò...é| 1 (francês socquette) substantivo masculino
>
> Peúga curta, geralmente até ao tornozelo.Ver imagem Palavras
>   relacionadas: soquetear, socate, feminela, batoca, socar .
>
> **so·que·te** |ê| 2 (soco + -ete) substantivo masculino
>
> 1. [Artilharia]  Espécie de maço roliço com que se calcava a pólvora no canhão de carregar pela boca.
> 2. Instrumento com que se calca a pólvora nos canudos dos foguetes.
> 3. Soco aplicado com pouca força.
> 4. [Brasil]  Espécie de sopa com ossos e pouca carne. Palavras relacionadas: socar, feminela, soquetear, socate, batoca .
>
> **so·que·te** |ê| 3 (inglês socket) substantivo masculino
>
> [Brasil]  Suporte, geralmente de porcelana ou de plástico, onde se
>   enrosca a lâmpada. = BOCAL, PORTA-LÂMPADAS
>
> "soquete", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
>   2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/soquete [consultado em
>   06-06-2016].

Alguém sabe a origem e se consta de algum dicionário? É correto usar?

Comment: Pode ser simplesmente uma extensão do significado de soquete 3 do Priberam por analogia do que aconteceu no inglês. A palavra inglesa *socket* tem esses significados todos: tomada (elétrica), bocal de lâmpada, network socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tradução está equivocada e não pode ser considerada definitiva.

"Soquete" nesse caso foi provavelmente traduzido por um programa como o google tradutor que geralmente traduz palavra por palavra.

Pesquisei na internet e o termo **"soquete bloqueante"** só é encontrado no stackoverflow. Por isso, fui pesquisar usando a sugestão do @Papa Lazzarou de **"conexão/ligação bloqueante"** e encontrei o termo **"socket bloqueante"**, que parece ser o mais usado em sites de hardware e em sites de universidades.

Segue os links com os usos:

[Sistemas de Operação – Sockets](https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ines/aulas/0910/SO/sockets.pdf)
[SOCKETS UDP, TCP E MULTICAST](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~bosco/ensino/ine5645/2014-1/0050-Sockets.pdf)

Ainda não há um termo definitivo, mas a maioria usa "socket" assim como no inglês.

Comment: Mas deve ter acontecido o mesmo com leiaute(layout), e agora está no dicionário. Será o SOpt a origem da palavra?!

Comment: Sim, porém para que uma palavra como **leiaute** entre no dicionário é preciso considerar motivos como uso e frequência na escrita, mas até que a palavra fosse inserida prevalecia o uso de layout. A minha sugestão é que enquanto não houver um termo oficial, o ideal é usar o termo mais utilizado pelas comunidades de software/hardware e universidades, pois quando o termo for inserido em um dicionário comum ou dicionário técnico será adicionado por um linguista e pode ser que seja diferente do termo "soquete bloqueante".

Comment: Infelizmente, não saberia dizer a origem da palavra, mas a maioria dos termos de informática e engenharia que vem do inglês tendem a permanecer no idioma.

Comment: Muito curiosa a tua forma de ver as coisas, gostei muito da resposta.

Answer (score 2):

O termo [*socket*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/socket) em inglês também tem o mesmo significado em inglês que a terceira acepção de *soquete* apresentado na pergunta ("light-bulb socket" *vis-à-vis* "bocal").

Assim, o uso de *socket* como termo técnico é mais uma analogia das Ciências de Computação de entidades abstratas a entidades concretas: é algo em que que você conecta ou desconecta outras peças conforme a necessidade (*e.g.*, "network socket" *vis-à-vis* "light-bulb socket").

Ao que parece, essa analogia soou razoável ao computeiro lusófono e, assim, o termo parece ter desenvolvido esse novo significado, com aroma de (ou, pelo menos, inspiração do) anglicismo.

Answer (score -1):

Eu considero que uma tradução mais acertada seria **conexão** ou **ligação**.

No contexto da pergunta indicada, o termo em inglês *socket* é utilizado para designar um componente de software que serve de ligação ou conexão de um programa a uma rede de comunicação.

Comment: Não, um _socket_ não é uma ligação, e pode até não suportar ligações. Por exemplo, _sockets_ UDP não estabelecem ligações, são apenas pontos de comunicação que podem receber (e enviar) pacotes.

Comment: Os sockets UDP não estabelecem ligações **explícitas** a outros componentes. Mas a servir como ponto de comunicação, um socket ganha o papel de conector entre o meio de comunicação e o componente que o invocou.

Comment: Mesmo admitindo que há uma "ligação implícita" (algo com que não concordo, já que 1) "ligação" tem um significado técnico que não é aqui satisfeito e que 2) é difícil ver que "ligação" estabeleço quando envio um pacote _multicast_), parece-me no mínimo impreciso chamar a um conector "ligação".

Comment: [conector](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/conector)

 | adj. | s. m. : 1. Que serve para **ligar** ou conectar.

Comment: Uma colher serve para comer. Posso concluir que é comida?

Comment: [falácia](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/fal%C3%A1cia) | s. f.

 3. Sofisma ou engano que se faz com razões falsas ou **mal deduzidas**.

Comment: Então como se traduz "unconnected socket"? "ligação não conectado" ou "conexão não ligado"? Se "um socket ganha o papel de conector", será que mesmo "conector" seria melhor tradução?